# access an existing database that is created and used by another application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have a rails app that should access some other databases for reading only. These Databases are created and used by other applications and I only need the to read.

Its not a problem to connect to these databases but I dont want to create a model for each table in these databases manually because there are some hundred tables. Is there a best practice for accessing a foreign database with rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can access foriegn databases in Rails application

Checkout this link

http://www.paultastic.com/showpage/Grabbing-Data-From-Foreign-Database-Using-Rails